# Get files from Ab-initio server to SFTP server

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sftp, ab-initio

I need the shell script to pull the .dat file from source server to SFTP server.

Every time the job runs, shell script has to verify if the table already exists in sftp server and get all the files corresponding to that table  with date greater than the existing file. (file comparison is required based on the date in the filename).

Example: Yesterday, job ran and file "table1_extract_20190101.dat" is extracted. And in source server, I have 2 files "table1_extract_20190102.dat", "table1_extract_20190103.dat". Then it has to get both the files and so on for each and every table.

Please suggest on how this could be implemented.

Thanks

Comment: Please show code of your shellscript...

Answer (score 0):

Use Ab Initio SFTP To component.

Ideally, add it at the end of the graph that creates the files, so all handling is in one place. The SFTP To component(s) would run in a new phase after the files are written.

Or, create another Ab Initio graph that looks for filenames based on the filename specification used to generate the original filenames. One risk is being sure the files have been written completely, which is why it is ideal to do it in the original graph. You would need to schedule this graph to run after the first graph is complete. A good way to do that is with a plan. Another way using Control>Center is to schedule this job after the previous one completes by adding a job dependency.